# Split a String into a determined number of parts (Haskell)

Tags: string, haskell, split

I'm trying to split a String in Haskell in several parts

Actually, I've already succeeded to split a `String` into a `[[Integer]]` but I'd want to have a `[[[Integer]]]`.

Here's what I've got :

```
parPaquets n [] = []
parPaquets n liste = (take n liste):parPaquets n (drop n liste)
```

What i'd want to have is : parPaquets :: Int -> [Integer] -> [[[Integer]]]

When I execute my function here's what I've got :

```
parPaquets 3 [1..10]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10]]
```

What I'd want to have in result of parPaquets 3 [1..10] :

```
[[[1,2,3]],[[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9]],[[10,0,0]]]
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Have you thought about writing another function that first applies `parPaquets`, and then apply another function to get the resulting function?

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you want to.  Your types aren't the same (`[[Integer]]` vs `[[[Integer]]]`) and in the desired result you've changed the output to also pad with `0`s.

Comment: Before writing a function, first define its type signature. That can help you a lot.

Comment: @Rhymoid : I haven't considered it but it seems to be a possibility.

Comment: @bheklir : That's what i wanted to say. Right now, my function is resulting in a [[Integer]] but I'd want it to result in a [[[Integer]]], same thing for the 0 s, I'd want the last split of my list to be completed with 0s. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough :/.

Comment: @MatijahSh : I have defined the signature that I desire, it is :  parPaquets :: Int -> [Integer] -> [[[Integer]]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix it up after the fact using `map (\x -> [x])`, or you can modify your function to put things in lists as you go:

```
parPaquets n liste = [take n liste]:parPaquets n (drop n liste)
```

By the way, your existing function is also available in the [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split) package under a few different names, e.g. [chunksOf](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v%3achunksOf). So you could also write

```
parPaquets n = map (\x -> [x]) . chunksOf n
```

Comment: Yeah ! That's exactly what I wanted, I'd just want to add those 0s to complete the last split of the result :) but thanks, it helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to my question ^^
Here's my solution. I'm sure it's not really some "beautiful" code but it's working so for the moment i'll accept it.

```
parPaquets :: Int -> [Integer] -> [[[Integer]]]
parPaquets n [] = []
parPaquets n liste = if ((toInteger(length(liste)) %% (toInteger n)) == (0 %% toInteger n)) then [take n liste]:parPaquets n (drop n liste) else parPaquets n (liste ++ [0])
```